# python Add values to file in new column if they match

Tags: python

I know this should be simple, but as I am new in python, I've been having some problems adding values and columns to a file. I have two files and I want to find line that match, if a line match I want a new column with value 1 and if the don't match the should get 0. This should be written in file-1 or in outPut. I have problem with adding the values.

Here my code until now:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

f1 = open('text-1.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('text-2.txt', 'r')

fileOne= f1.readlines()
fileTwo = f2.readlines()

outPut = open('output.txt', 'w')

for x,y in zip(fileOne,fileTwo):
    if x==y:
        outPut.write("\t".join(x) + 1)

    else:
        outPut.write("\t".join(x) + 0)


f1.close()
f2.close()
outPut.close
```

Any suggestions or is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: this way you are comparing line 1 of file 1 with line 1 of file 2 and so on.. is this what you want? Also I'm not sure what you mean by column, can you provide a sample of how the output file should look like or looks like right now?

Comment: I assume this works? At least, it appears to do what you want. In that case, you might be better off at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It will help a lot if you provide some sample input and expected output files. Are the two input files always going to have the same number of lines? If not, then your code may not work correctly. Also, you probably want `outPut.write("\t".join(x) + " 1")` and `outPut.write("\t".join(x) + " 0")`. Do you really want each character of `x` separated by `\t` in the output? Also, what is your goal here? Have you looked at the [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) module of Python? Maybe that can help if you are trying to compare text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it now, your code produces an error: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`. This error occurs when you do `"\t".join(x) + 1`, because the result of `join` is a string, and `1` is an integer. You should surround the number in quotes: `outPut.write("\t".join(x) + "1")`

Now your code runs. Using these files as input:

text-1.txt

```
foo
bar
baz
```

text-2.txt

```
qux
bar
qux
```

The output is:

```
f   o   o   
0b  a   r   
1b  a   z0
```

This probably isn't quite what you want; I'm guessing you want each line as it originally appears, followed by a tab, followed by a 1 or 0. If that is what you want, then `outPut.write("\t".join(x) + "1")` is not the way to do it. `"\t".join(x)` inserts a tab character between every character in the original text. If you want the unmodified text plus a tab plus a number, then do `outPut.write(x + "\t1")`.

The output now is:

```
foo
    0bar
    1baz    0
```

This is closer - there's no longer a tab between every character, but the numbers are appearing on the wrong line. This is because `x` is the contents of the original line, *including* the ending newline. If you want the number to occur before the newline, then you'll have to strip out the newline, and add a new one at the end: `outPut.write(x.rstrip() + "\t1\n")`

```
f1 = open('text-1.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('text-2.txt', 'r')

fileOne= f1.readlines()
fileTwo = f2.readlines()

outPut = open('output.txt', 'w')

for x,y in zip(fileOne,fileTwo):
    if x==y:
        outPut.write(x.rstrip() + "\t1\n")

    else:
        outPut.write(x.rstrip() + "\t0\n")


f1.close()
f2.close()
outPut.close()
```

The output is now:

```
foo 0
bar 1
baz 0
```

Which matches your stated requirements: the original content of text-1, plus a new column with value 1 if it matches, and 0 if it doesn't match.

Comment: yes, thank you. That should work. The only thing, "zip()" seems to compress the files to the shortest one, what for me  is not useful since I want to keep the original list. I also try with izip.longest(), but the values f "y" are wrong, all values will be 0 until now. What I am missing here? (sorry for late answer, i am traveling)